# Will peewee's SqliteQueueDatabase work with multiple processes?

Tags: sqlite, peewee

[SqliteQueueDatabase](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#sqliteq) is supposed to solve the locking issue, allowing many threads to write simultanously. Does this work with multiple **processes**?

Answer (score 2):

The SqliteQueueDatabase is not aware of multiple connections that may be running in separate processes -- only threads.